# Interpretar respostas de cartão respota

Tags: c#, processamento-de-imagens

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca que seja capaz de processar uma imagem escaneada de um formulário de respostas(semelhante ao utilizado no ENEM).
Já encontrei um software que é capaz de fazer isso, que é o [KaptureAll](http://www.hsinformatica.com.br/publique/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?infoid=415&sid=94), porém gostaria de saber se existe alguma solução open source que faça algo semelhante.

Caso não exista, qual a melhor forma de fazê-lo, que bibliotecas vocês recomendariam?

Comment: Olá Charles. Esse site não é um fórum, e as perguntas precisam ser mais objetivas sob um problema específico ou algo passível de ser respondido com uma única resposta. Se não leu ainda, por favor leia a [help] e [ask]. De todas as formas, talvez você possa construir algo por conta própria (não sei se OCR te ajuda, porque seu objetivo não é reconhecer caracteres e sim identificar padrões). Uma biblioteca de código aberto e famosa é o [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). Pesquisa sobre limiarização (que é o processo de separar as marcas de respostas do fundo).

Comment: Ok, irei pesquisar, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de fazer é ir atrás de uma biblioteca OCR (Optical Character Recognition). [Aqui tem um artigo ótimo sobre isso](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160868/A-C-Project-in-Optical-Character-Recognition-OCR-U).

Existe ainda o Tesseract, mecanismo de OCR que não é nativo do .NET, mas que [existe uma envelopagem para o .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/).

Ou, ainda, você pode tentar [uma solução paga](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/c%23-sharp.net-ocr-api-overview.html).